# Edit DOORS Views in DXL Without Opening Module

Tags: view, ibm-doors

I have a DXL script that gets data from an input source, and dynamically modifies the views of existing modules.  I've figured out how to do this, but my current approach requires me to first open up the module, modify the view definitions, and then close the module.

When this is done in batch, it results in a bunch of windows opening up, hoarding the window focus on my computer.  I want to do the same thing - modify these view definitions - but if possible, I'd like to avoid opening the module.

Is this possible?  How can I modify view data without opening the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time DXL programmer and as far as I know this cannot be done. To modify a view you must open the module. Sorry, that is probably not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: It is what it is.  Thanks for confirming this!

Answer (score 0):

```
Module  currentModule = read(Module1,false)
current = currentModule
```

False will not let the code open the module.. if you set that with true, it will open the module

Answer (score 0):

There is a rumour that it might work with the following approach:

- use batch mode
- open the module (edit)
- remember the current default view for the user
- modify the module so that the view to be modified is the default view
- close module
- open it again
- now the view should be active and it should be possible to modify columns
- save the view under the old name
- restore the old default view
- save module and close it